# Definitive guide to understanding how to formulate an IPv6 address

Tags: ipv6

For fun, I'd like to better understand the building blocks or elements that are within an IPv6 address.

Here are the basics, from my understanding:

- IPv6 addresses are 128 bits long (written as 8 blocks, each with 16 bits)
- Each block is encoded as hex digits between 0 and 0xffff. Leading zeroes may be omitted.
- One can append an IPv4 doted-quad address, and it will occupy the lower 32 bits of the IPv6 address.
  1:2:3:4:5:6:200.201.202.203. (The rules for the IPv4 are as expected.)
- The IPv4 representation can only appear at the end.
- It is possible to use double colons syntax to represent one or more blocks with zeroes.
  1:2::7:8 is equivalent to 1:2:0:0:0:0:7:8.
- Each IPv6 address may only have one double colon within it, otherwise it is syntactically wrong.
- Double colon may appear at the beginning, middle or end of an ip6, but not within an IPv4 dotted-quad address.

Are all the above points correct?

Please don't tell me to read the RFC. There are several about this matter, and none actually comes with a few simple examples to describe the various encoding mechanisms. I'm sure many would appreciate a simple list with examples.

**Online testing tool**
The closest online tool to help is 
http://www.dominicsayers.com/source/beta/is_email/test/
but the messages are confusing and it does not actually say in plain English what is right and wrong and why. It's also actually built for emails which of course may contain IPv6 addresses, so its not exactly ideal.

Comment: The dominicsayers link to the is_email/test program is broken, unfortunately.

Comment: In an IPv4 address you can omit middle zero-quads.  Eg, 10.0.0.248 can be written 10.248.  I'm not sure if you can do that at the tail end of an IPv6 address though, like 1:2:3:4:5:6:10.248.

Comment: You can only use double colons once. If any other blocks are :0000: you can shorten each to :0:.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, yes, your points are correct.

Are you sure you read the RFC? [RFC 3513, section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3513#section-2.2) has exactly what you are asking for. It's very well written, for an RFC. =) I can't help but point this out since it may be very helpful to future people reading this question.

Comment: I hope i read the correct RFC, as there are a few that are related. 2.2 does include some samples but it does not include any examples of easy to make mistakes... For example it does not include an ip6 with two empty :: blocks with a note why this is wrong...

Comment: @mP, Well, it does say `The "::" can only appear once in an address.`, but you're right that it doesn't say why. If you think about it, it's not too difficult to figure out why. Imagine an address like `::1::`, which could expand to 6 unique addresses. It's ambiguous to allow two, and in cases where it wouldn't be ambiguous, it would be useless.

Comment: [RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952) has updated the standard for the canonical text representation for IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously this bit is a typo:

> it is possible to use double colons syntax to represent one or more blocks with zeroes. 1:2::6:7 is equivalent to 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8.

`1:2::6:7` means `1:2:0:0:0:0:6:7`.

I hadn't heard this before:

> double colon may [not appear] within an ip4 dot address.

But I made a test program, and it seems to confirm it.

```
$ ./testipv6 0:0:0:0:0:0:192.168.0.1
0:0:0:0:0:0:192.168.0.1: OK

$ ./testipv6 0:0:0:0:0:0:192.168::1
0:0:0:0:0:0:192.168::1: ERROR
```

Otherwise I think everything you said is OK.

---

**testipv6.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int convert(const char *addr)
{
    struct in6_addr dst;

    return inet_pton(AF_INET6, addr, (void *)&dst);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: testipv6 <addr>\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    while (argc > 1) {
        argc--, argv++;
        const char *addr = argv[0];

        if (convert(addr)) {
            printf("%s: OK\n", addr);
        } else {
            printf("%s: ERROR\n", addr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo spotting. I myself arent exactly sure as there are so many exceptions. Take a look at the nonsense that is possible with emails - one can embed comments inthere.. That may be obsolete but why it was ever included is beyond me. I tried writing a program but this sort of blackbox testing might leave out some weird cases i am not aware of :)

Comment: I only gave the points to mike because he found a snippet in the official rfc.

Comment: +1 for the source code. Sometimes the best way to learn something is to experience it for yourself. =) Plus, it's a good introduction to inet_pton() which anyone coding C for IPv6 would need to know about.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 addresses with zone ID has a unique notation though its not specific to the address itself. In a system with multiple IPv6 enabled interfaces the link local address has to be disambiguated in some way. Its done using the "%" notation.

*FE80::AA%eth0* refers to the link local address reachable through the eth0 interface. 
It can be an interface index in some plaforms, *FE80::AA%10*